# C++ Pointer movement

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{ 
    char *A[] = { "abcx", "dbba", "cccc"}; 
    char var = *(A+1) - *A+1; 
    cout << (*A + var); 
}
```

Hi, the code gives output bba. I am unable understand, how the integer value of var becomes 6. In what order, the var value is solved. Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: here ya go https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: What makes you think the integer value of `var` is `6`? Did you examine its value directly?

Comment: When I print int(var), it shows 6.

Comment: Did you try adding more output or inspecting the program under a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is an array of pointers to character arrays. AKA, strings. Each array is 5 characters long because of the 4 character string literals, each of which has one hidden null terminator.

Because you **got lucky** and your compiler does **the simple thing**, the character literals are placed into the program one after the other.

So *A is the address of the first array. *(A+1) is the address of the second array. Subtract them and that is 5. Add 1 for 6.

This kind of C code is obfuscated. It can also be dangerous. I would not rely on accessing through a pointer outside of an array even if you are pretty sure there's a second array following. Assuming that will only lead to pain. And suffering.

Because `*A + var` when `var` is greater than the array size is **undefined behavior**. In this case the valid array size is 5, so valid values of `var` are 0..4.

Undefined behavior means that the compiler's optimizer is allowed to assume that it does not happen. Because if your program *DID* have undefined behavior, it would not be a defined program and would automatically be **WRONG**. So obviously you'd never do that. Hah.

Here's some modified code that will hopefully explain better:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char *A[] = {"abcx", "dbba", "cccc"};
  char var = *(A + 1) - *A + 1;
  std::cout << (void *)*A << std::endl;
  std::cout << (void *)*(A + 1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (*A + var) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Running it:

```
0x402010
0x402015
bba
```

Those are memory addresses on my particular machine, yours may be different. But the important thing is they are 5 bytes different.

Now I'm going to use a hex dump tool called `xxd`. You can find other good ones. If I dump the binary executable as hex and search for `dbba` I find a line:

```
00002010: 6162 6378 0064 6262 6100 0000 011b 033b  abcx.dbba......;
```

Oh wait, let me rebuild that without optimization. See what I mean about this being risky business?

```
00002010: 6162 6378 0064 6262 6100 6363 6363 0000  abcx.dbba.cccc..
```

The optimizer had completely removed the third array element from the binary because no one used it.

If we'd written the code just a little differently the optimizer could have removed *both* the second and third array element and you'd be trying to print binary garbage data.

Comment: In the second sentence, the two values are the addresses of (the first character of) two unrelated string literals, so it is undefined behaviour to subtract them

Comment: Hi Zan, thanks a lot for answering. But, still I have a doubt. How do you say the value of *A is 5 and that of *(A+1) is 10. Does not A represent the base address value? Pls help.

Comment: I actually found this explaination on the net. Precedence of (pointer)* >(binary) +, and order of execution of ‘*’ is right to left . If ‘A’ address is ‘x’ then address of ‘*(A+1)’ is ‘x+6’ and address of ‘*A+1’ is ‘x+1’. So integer value of var = 6 (total no of character between two points (x+6)-(x+1)+1). During printing the operator ‘+’ is overloaded now the pointer points to ‘x+7’ . For this reason the output of the program.    Pls help me understand how the address of A is x and that of *(A+1) is x+6? Thanks in advance.